# WP CLI: there has been critical error

Tags: wp-cli

I am using Wordpress 5.3 minimal installation and currently have not installed any other plugins. I have installed WP CLI and below is the output of `wp-info`:

```
OS: Linux 5.0.0-1025-gcp #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 11 13:09:18 UTC 2019 x86_64
Shell:  /bin/bash
PHP binary: /usr/bin/php7.3
PHP version:    7.3.8-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
php.ini used:   /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
WP-CLI root dir:    phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli
WP-CLI vendor dir:  phar://wp-cli.phar/vendor
WP_CLI phar path:   /www/ppesupplies_777/public
WP-CLI packages dir:    /www/ppesupplies_777/.wp-cli/packages/
WP-CLI global config:   
WP-CLI project config:  
WP-CLI version: 2.4.0
```

I am trying to play with WP CLI and each and every command of WP CLI gives me below error:
`Error: There has been a critical error on your website.Learn more about debugging in WordPress. There has been a critical error on your website.`

I have checked error logs, enabled `wp_debug` etc but I can't seem to find anything that can help me know what is going wrong. Any help appreciated.